# Use a state with objects as options in dropdown menu : REACT

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dropdown

Creating dummy website with a few functional aspects. Just to clarify, I started learning React a week ago so please be kind with your answers. Thank you!

Initially created a state in App.js that allows me to add and delete clients. (like the corny to-do list)

Now using a different component where I can 'add a lesson' I want to have a dropdown selector where I can choose one of the existing clients from the other state as my option. I have created everything so far that takes the inputs and console.log() is showing that everything is going through fine. However, I can't seem to get the dropdown options to show as the existing clients so I can add the lesson in a different state. To clarify I have 2 states, clients and lessons(with the existing clients).

Here is my App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Clients from './components/Clients'
import AddClient from './components/AddClient'
import NavBar from './components/NavBar'
import AddLesson from './components/AddLesson'

    class App extends Component {
      state = {
        clients : [
          {id : 1 , name : 'bob', price : 30},
          {id : 2 , name : 'mary', price : 40},
          {id : 3 , name : 'greg', price : 45}
        ],
        lessons : [
          {id: null, name: '', time: null}
        ]
      }

      deleteClient = (id) => {
        let clients = this.state.clients.filter(client => {
          return client.id !== id
        })
        this.setState({
          clients: clients
        })
      }

      addClient = (newClient) => {
        newClient.id = Math.random();
        let clients = [...this.state.clients, newClient];
        clients.sort((a, b) => a.name.localeCompare(b.name))
        this.setState({
            clients: clients,
        })
      }

      addLesson = (newLesson) => {
        newLesson.id = Math.random(); 
        let lessons = [...this.state.lessons, newLesson];
        this.setState({
            lessons: lessons,
        })
        console.log(lessons)
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div className="App">
            <NavBar/>
            <Clients clients={this.state.clients} deleteClient={this.deleteClient}/>
            <AddClient addClient={this.addClient}/>
            <AddLesson addLesson={this.addLesson}/>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

Here is AddLesson.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'

class AddLesson extends Component {
    state = {
        lessons: [
            {id : null, name: '', time: null}
        ]
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.id] : e.target.value
        })
    } 

    handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.props.addLesson(this.state);
        e.target.reset();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="text-center">
                <h2>Add a lesson</h2>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

                    <select name="lesson_client">
                        <option>{this.props.clients}</option>
                    </select>

                    {/* <label htmlFor="name">Client Name: </label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" onChange={this.handleChange}/><br/>
                    <label htmlFor="time">Lesson Duration (in hours): </label>
                    <input type="text" id="time" onChange={this.handleChange}/><br/>
                    <button className="btn btn-primary">Add Client</button> */}
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default AddLesson
```

I tried not to overload with code, so if I am missing something, please let me know and I will edit it.

Comment: I also have a Clients.js that actually renders out to the user the list of Clients. If that is needed I can also post that.

Comment: Sorry, to understand, are you trying to render the client list inside the `AddLesson` component? If so, your not passing the clients through as a prop.

Comment: You are looking for: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: @Kurtis yes, I want the client list to show up as the options in the dropdown list. I thought that because the AddLesson.js is a class based component, the props get passed down automatically?

Comment: Only the React stuff gets passed down automatically. You need to do two things. Firstly add ` <AddLesson addLesson={this.addLesson} clients={this.state.clients} />` to `App.js`. Secondly you need to map over the clients like Avanthika has answered below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop over clients & render them.

```
<select onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)} name="lesson_client">
  {this.props.clients.map(client => <option key={client.id} value={client.price}>{client.name}</option>)}
</select>
```

You can listen to `handleChange` to read the selected value. (Note: I have changed `e.target.id` to `e.target.name` since there is no id attr on select tag)

```
handleChange = (e) => {
  this.setState({
    [e.target.name] : e.target.value
  })
}
```

And I also noticed you are not passing `clients` to `AddLesson` component. Please pass it for the code to work.

`<AddLesson clients={this.state.clients} addLesson={this.addLesson}/>`

Comment: He's not using that `handleChange` function for the dropdown. That is used in the text fields that are commented out so changing id would break those. Nice edits after my comment above :-)

Comment: Umm ya, just noticed the commented code, he can reuse handleChange with name attribute!

Comment: question: where in <select></select> is the [e.target.name] ?

Comment: The attr name="lesson_client" should do the trick for you! `<select name="lesson_client"></select>`